# LilyPond tie doesn't work as expecting with two voices

Tags: notation, sheet-music, lilypond

I want to connect two `b2.`, but the output connected the `g`. How to make this work?

An explanation of this issue will be more grateful.

[image: output]

```
\version "2.18.2"

{
  \clef bass
  \time 3/4
  <<
    { \voiceOne <d g>4.( g8 fis e e4 b,2) }
    { \voiceTwo  b2.^~ b2. }
  >>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only using a single voice here, putting everything in parallel music (note how everything is put onto the same stem and how `\voiceTwo` trumps `\voiceOne` ?).

You need to either write `<< ... \\ ... >>` (in which case `\voiceOne` and `voiceTwo` will be implicitly used in the two created voices and need not be specified) or `<< \new Voice ... \new Voice ... >>`.

Note the `\\` in the middle of the first option: that is a game changer creating separate voices and giving them separate voice styles.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer already given:

The solution to automatically create two voices via `\\` is given by

```
\version "2.18.2"

{
  \clef bass
  \time 3/4
  <<
    { <d g>4.( g8 fis e e4 b,2) }
    \\
    { b2.^~ b2. }
  >>
}
```

But this actually produces

[image]

The key point here is that, in such a multiple-voice construction, **the first voice that you input, by default, will appear stems up** (that is, it's treated as the upper voice). And since the `<d g>` is the lower voice, we want stems down. So a better option would be:

```
\version "2.18.2"

{
  \clef bass
  \time 3/4
  <<
    { b2.^~ b2. }
    \\
    { <d g>4.( g8 fis e e4 b,2) }
  >>
}
```

which compiles

[image]

Comment: Very appreciated for your additional answer, it's explicit and rich my knowledge to multiple-voice.